# Show that $2^n\to0$ $2$-adically

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

I have no idea how to do this question. Can anyone give any suggestions?

Given a rational sequence $a: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, we say that $\underline{a}$ converges to $l$ (here $l$ is a rational number) p-adically", when for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N>0$, such that, if $n>N$, then $|a_n - l|_p<\epsilon$. Show that the rational sequence, $a_n = 2^n$, converges to 0, in the sense of $2$-adic absolute value. Thus, we would say that,
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^n=0$.

Comment: So $a_n = 2^n$, $l=0$, and $a_n-l = 2^n$. Do you know how to find $|2^n|_2$?

Comment: how do you define $|.|_{p}$?

Comment: Well $|2^n - 0|_2 = |2^n|_2 = 1/2^n$ so .....

Comment: Sorry I am dense, but how do you find $|2^n|_2$? How is it equal to $1/2^n$?

Comment: Marlesque: Have you looked up the definition of the $2$-adic valuation $|x|_2$? It says precisely that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two definitions involved this question.

First, the notion of p-adic absolute value defined by $|x|_p=p^{-v_p(x)}$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ where $v_p$ is the [p-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) and also the notion of convergence with this absolute value. This is the convergence associated to the metric distance $d_p(x,y)=|x-y|_p$. In other words, $x_n\rightarrow x$ iff $|x_n-x|_p\rightarrow 0$ as a sequence of real numbers.

Now to prove that $2^n\rightarrow 0$ with this notion of convergence you just have to prove that $|2^n-0|_2\rightarrow 0$ as a sequence of real numbers. But this is easy because $|2^n|_2=2^{-v_2{2^n}}=2^{-n}$.